# Using functions to output strings or characters. Noob

Tags: c++, function

I have an input file named animals.dat that I need my program to read and output the files in block format.  For example the file reads:

TIGER
DOG
CAT

It needs to output

TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT (T would be 1x20 as it's the first character in the word and 20th letter in the alphabet)

IIIIIIIII
IIIIIIIII (I 2x9 as it's the 2nd character and 9th in the alphabet)

I've tried to set up functions to do this but my output kinda goes insane, outputting just TONS of one character at a time, and I'm pretty sure not even doing the rows.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ifstream fin;
ofstream fout;

void rectangle(char ch, int alphacount,int count) {
int height=1, width=0;
while(width <= alphacount && height <= count) {

    while(width <= alphacount) {
        fout << ch;
        cout << ch;
        width++;
    }
    cout << endl;

    if(height <= count) {
        fout << ch << endl;
        cout << ch << endl;
        height++;
    }
}
}

int main(void) {
 fin.open("animals.dat");
fout.open("out.dat");
 int count=0, alphacount=0;
 char ch, x='A';
 while(!fin.eof()) {
    fin >> ch;
    while(x!=ch) {
        x++;
        alphacount++;
    }
    rectangle(ch, alphacount, count);

    count++;
    if(ch =='\n') {
        alphacount = 0;
        count = 0;
        x = 0;
    }
}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: _'What am I doing wrong?'_ Please use a debugger to find out, before asking here. If you have particular questions about behavior you don't understand and that can't be explained from the c++ reference documentation, ask such please!

Comment: you might start with resetting `x` to a reasonable value on occasion...

Comment: Your code is very convoluted and I'm not sure what your intent is.  For example you describe making a 1x20 array of T's, but your code makes it look like you're trying to print a 20x20 square of T's.  Take it in small steps.  First try printing out the number that you want for each letter, see if you've got that right.  If you want the number '20' for T, you don't need to use a loop, just arithmetic, like `'T'-'A'+1` maybe with some appropriate casting.  Then do a separate function that prints out 20 'T''s, or 9 'I''s and get that working before combining it with your other code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I apologize for the imprecise way of asking.  Just kinda needing some direction here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that I see:

1. The function `rectangle` can be easily simplified. You just need two `for` loops.

   ```
   void rectangle(char ch, int alphacount,int count)
   {
      for ( int height = 0; height < count; ++height )
      {
         for ( int width = 0; width < alphacount; ++width )
         {
            fout << ch;
            cout << ch;
         }
         cout << endl;
      }
   }
   ```
2. You don't need `x` at all because you can compute `alphacount` directly using arithmetic.
3. You can move `alphacount` inside the `while` loop.
4. The code inside the `while` loop can be simplified to:

   ```
   while(!fin.eof())
   {
      int alphacount = 0;
      count++;
      char ch;
      fin >> ch;
      if ( isalpha(ch) )
      {
         if ( ch > 'Z' )
         {
            // It's a lower case letter.
            alphacount = ch - 'a' + 1;
         }
         else
         {
            // It's an upper case letter.
            alphacount = ch - 'A' + 1;
         }
         rectangle(ch, alphacount, count);
      }

      if(ch =='\n')
      {
         count = 0;
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: First off, thank you very much, this is much more clear and elegant.  However the output is giving me 5 rows of I instead of 2, any reasons why?

I edited the file to where it's only:
TI

Comment: @Skathix I am not sure why. When I ran the program I got two rows of 'I's.

Comment: The `while (!fin.eof())` should be changed to `while (fin >> ch)`.  This can be found by searching StackOverflow.

Comment: What is the difference in these two statements?

Comment: also while (fin >> ch) screws the output up.

Comment: One other question @R.Sahu, my counter isn't resetting when the data file hits a line break.  Any advice?  I'm needing it to reset after every word (I.E. TIGER DOG CAT)

Comment: @Skathix, (fin >> ch) must skip white spaces. I looked in the standard hearder files and it does not specify a function to read `char` using `operator>>`. Perhaps another strategy, such as `fin.getc()` might be more portable.

Answer (score 1):

You're not reinitializing `x` and `alphacount` within the outer loop. Your code should look like this:

```
while(!fin.eof())
{
    int alphacount=0;
    char ch, x='A';

    fin >> ch;
    .
    .
    .
```

A debugger would have found this problem for you in much less time than it took to write your question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm extremely new and unfamiliar with debugging, do you have any advice on how to learn this?

Comment: @Skathix I'm pretty sure sure you'll find tons of comprehensive tutorials _'How to debug'_ for your particular toolchain/IDE just googling for it.

Comment: @Skathix what platform are you working on? If you're using linux I highly recommend playing around with GDB

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ That's a great call, I don't know why my head shuts down when I start asking for advice.  Thank you.